# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:794)

Tags: jsp

Below is the exception which I got all of sudden, the same code works locally and test system, its failing in Dev environments, all configuration are same in all layers.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:604)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.overstock.spring.security.filter.WebAuthenticationFormPopulatingFilter.doHttpFilter(WebAuthenticationFormPopulatingFilter.java:43)
    at com.overstock.spring.security.filter.AbstractHttpServletFilterBean.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletFilterBean.java:20)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.overstock.spring.security.filter.WebAuthenticationUrlCheckingFilter.doHttpFilter(WebAuthenticationUrlCheckingFilter.java:72)
    at com.overstock.spring.security.filter.AbstractHttpServletFilterBean.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletFilterBean.java:20)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.overstock.spring.security.ils.filter.UserInfoCookieSetterFilter.doHttpFilter(UserInfoCookieSetterFilter.java:51)
    at com.overstock.spring.security.filter.AbstractHttpServletFilterBean.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletFilterBean.java:20)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.overstock.ui.ServiceUsageTrackingFilter.doHttpFilter(ServiceUsageTrackingFilter.java:34)
    at com.overstock.ui.AbstractHttpServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.overstock.ui.scope.ProcessingScopeFilter.doHttpFilter(ProcessingScopeFilter.java:71)
    at com.overstock.ui.AbstractHttpServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:311)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:794)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1207)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:840)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:859)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1781)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilati…
```

Comment: show code related to the exception `java.util.NoSuchElementException` which will be thrown because you were calling `next()` method of `Iterator` which doesn't contain any element.

Comment: can please help me, i am getting the same exception but in my case because of these two tags  
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>    if i comment these it is not giving the above exception ,but i have to use these

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error, turned out to be a bug in Tomcat. The issue for me was an empty attribute on an HTML tag in a JSP file. For example:

<body **ui-view=""**></body>

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56561

Per the bug report, fixed in 8.0.9, 7.0.55, and 6.0.42

Answer (score 0):

from your exception `java.util.NoSuchElementException` is the root cause.

some where you used `Iterator#next()` to access `ArrayList` elements, without checking any element exists or not. better to avoid these `NoSuchElementException` always call `Iterator#hasNext()` before.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually the same code base works fine in different environment.